# Not able to insert the rows which contain '#' special Character from CSV file to SQl database,using SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, csv, unicode, ssis

When i am trying to import the CSV file into SQL tables using SSIS packages i was not able to insert the rows which contain '#' as special character.

It is throwing the following error:

> '[DCNV - Unicode to NonUnicode [14]] Error: The "DCNV - Unicode to
>   NonUnicode.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[PrimaryAddr1]"
>   failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition
>   on "DCNV - Unicode to NonUnicode.Outputs[Data Conversion
>   Output].Columns[PrimaryAddr1]" specifies failure on truncation. A
>   truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.'

Please help me with this issue. How can i allow '**#**' special character to insert into Database tables. The column related to this issues are `Customer Address(DT_WSTR)`

Comment: Please solve this issue.. it is very urgent and important issue to be fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source as well as the destination data types to make sure you are specifying them correctly - Jet has probably guessed wrong - it only looks at the first few rows to guess what datatype your data is.

Also notice there error is actually complaining about Unicode to NonUnicode - make sure the source/destination lengths are correct and depict your data.

Comment: Yes the source and destination have the same datatypes and also same lengths but still this error is occurring.It is allowing to insert all the other records except the records which have '#' as character in that text. If i remove that '#' then,the import is successful. But i need to insert the '#' also into database as it is not correct to change the text as my convenience. So please give me solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post an example of the file with it not working - I'll take a look.

Comment: I am not able to post the file..'1# ST CHECHENG ROAD. EAST.and '1# 1ST CHECHENG ROAD. EAST LONGQUAN' these are the two records which have '#' as character. The source column have 'Unicode DT_WSTR' as the Datatype and The destination column have 'DT_STR" as the datatype both have the dame lengths of '255'

Comment: I've just tried a sample I knocked up myself and worked fine, I can't really help unless you pass across an actual file that I can use to repro.